# Is "app" folder name reserved when aliasing in react typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

TS compiler says module not found when trying to path alias in tsconfig.

[image]

it works whenever there is no app folder in the paths.

[image]

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "paths": {
      "modules/*": ["modules/*"],
      "app_core/*": ["app/core/*"],
      "core/*": ["core/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}
```

As shown in the picture, when I use the app_core module the compiler says module not found

[image]

```js
//import TestModule from "app/core/test/Test.module"; //doesnot work
import TestModule from "core/test/Test.module"; //works fine

import PageModule from "modules/Page.module"; //works fine
import React from "react";
import "./App.css";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <TestModule />
      <PageModule />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

but the other one works fine. Don't know if the folder name is reserved of something. Can someone help me out?
Thank you in advance.